# Аккордеон на чистом Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var panelItem = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-title'),
  bodyItem = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-body');


panelItem.forEach(function(item, i, panelItem) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (this.classList.contains('panel-active')) {
      bodyItem[i].classList.remove('active');
      this.classList.remove('panel-active');
    } else {
      item[i].classList.remove('panel-active');
      panelItem[i].classList.remove('panel-active');
      bodyItem[i].classList.remove('active');
      this.classList.add('panel-active');
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.panel-title {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.panel-active {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #1</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #2</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #3</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Всем привет. Есть проблема одна, есть код аккордеона, сейчас он не работает, нужно чтобы если активен один блок, то кликая на другой блок тот блок который был активен закрывается а тот блок по которому кликнули должен открываться. Проблема тут в том что я не могу удалить класс всем предыдущим заголовкам у которых есть активный класс. В частности ошибка на 12 строке, я не много понимаю почему такая ошибка, но не пойму как ее решить. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил суть проблемы, у меня плохо получается расписывать вот так все)[image: Код]

Comment: `item` - это не массив, а элемент массива `panelItem`

Comment: @Dimava я это понял, спасибо за пример !

Answer (score 7):

```js
var panelItem = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-title'),
  bodyItem = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-body');
panelItem.__proto__.forEach = [].__proto__.forEach;

var activePanel;
panelItem.forEach(function(item, i, panelItem) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //show new thingy;
    this.classList.add('panel-active');
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    //hide old thingy
    if (activePanel) {
      activePanel.classList.remove('panel-active');
      activePanel.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    }
    //update thingy
    activePanel = (activePanel === this) ? 0 : this;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.panel-title {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.panel-active {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #1</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #2</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #3</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поправил открытие последнего закрытого

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Можно немного облегчить код, заменив класс `.active` для panel-body, на стиль `.panel-active + .panel-body`

А также, воспользовавшись тем, что [функция getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает *живую* коллекцию.

```js
var panelItem = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-title'),
  active = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-active');

Array.from(panelItem).forEach(function(item, i, panelItem) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (active.length > 0 && active[0] !== this) // если есть активный элемент, и это не тот по которому кликнули
      active[0].classList.remove('panel-active'); // убрать класс panel-active

    // изменить состояние класса panel-active на текущем элементе: добавить если не было, убрать если было.
    this.classList.toggle('panel-active');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.panel-title {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.panel-active {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.panel-active + .panel-body {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #1</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #2</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #3</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за пример!

Answer (score 3):

Мой вариант

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.panel-title'), function(item) {
 item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  display=(this.nextElementSibling.style.display=='block') ? 'none' : 'block';
  [].forEach.call(this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.panel-body'), function(panels) {
   panels.style.display='none';
  });
  this.nextElementSibling.style.display=display;
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.panel-title {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.panel-active {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.panel-active + .panel-body {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #1</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #2</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Group Item #3</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Переписывается реторический за, щеке сбить, если большой языкового ему алфавит составитель силуэт меня страну рукопись языком вопроса толку оксмокс она.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```